# Implicty wait selenium Python 2.7 not working

Tags: python, selenium, wait

I am scraping public linkedIn data from specific people. 
here is the code inside the while loop. For you to know, I used time.sleep() for the first 400 profils urls and it worked. However, it is not working anymore as it makes my firefox browser crash. I am pretty sure that the bug comes from the time.sleep() function that I tried to modify using implictly_wait() and WebdriverWait. However, none of this tries worked ;(

Here the code inside the while loop with the time.sleep() function that worked for around 400urls:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
    time.sleep(4)
    username = browser.find_element_by_id("session_key-login")
    password = browser.find_element_by_id("session_password-login")
    username.send_keys("yourmail")
    password.send_keys("yourpassword")
    login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
    login_attempt.submit()

    time.sleep(4)
    browser.get(the profile link I wanna scrap)


    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

    formation = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "education"})
    nom = soup.find_all('span', {'class': "full-name"})

    for a in nom:
        for b in formation:    
            print(a.text,b.text)
    time.sleep(4)      

    browser.close()
```

I tried to replace the time.sleep() by Implicitly_wait() but it is not working. The browser does not wait at all.

I also tried this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("the profile url I wanna scrap")
    delay = 30 # seconds
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by('education'))
        print("Page is ready!")

    except TimeoutException:

        print("Loading took too much time!")
```

But it is still not working.
Do you have any idea on how to solve the issue ? 
If I could make the browser wait without using time.sleep() (which makes my browser crash) without any conditions that would be amazing ! 
other question ? If I use chrome instead of firefox, do I have a chance to overcome the problem ?

Thanks for your answers,
Raphaël

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Hi RemcoW ! while using implictly_wait() or WebDriverWait with conditions I got no error but the browser does not wait...

Answer (score 0):

With WebDriverWait, the browser waits but firefox crashes again: here the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
username = browser.find_element_by_id("session_key-login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("session_password-login")
username.send_keys("mail")
password.send_keys("password")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "content")))



finally:
    browser.get("profil linkedin to scrap")

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

formation = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "education"})
nom = soup.find_all('span', {'class': "full-name"})

for a in nom:
    for b in formation:    
            print(a.text,b.text)

browser.close()
```

Comment: you need to edit your original question instead of posting it as an answer.